# If black hole is a "hole", how can its position be pinpointed from every position in universe?

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, singularities, event-horizon

Ok, this is going to sound lame but, here goes: When we say that a black hole is situated at a distance of 1 light year(let) FROM EARTH, that means it may situated at a distance of 100 light years from a planet in andromeda. Now, the universe is homogenoeus, and we assume that that from every planet the position of black hole can be pinpointed.  Now my question is, internet impression of a black hole is like a "hole" in space, like a hole in a paper. But we can see a black hole from every position in universe(assumed), implying that black hole is three dimensional shape(optically speaking), but that would mean that black hole is not infinite. Now, if its not infinite, thus it may have a shape, and thus notion of "wormholes" would not exis????

Comment: 1. Your numbers are off, no object can be 1 lyr from us and 100 lyrs from something in Andromeda. 2. It's not clear what you're asking - why would you think that one cannot determine the location of a hole in a paper, and furthermore, what about the event horizon is not a "three-dimensional shape"?

Comment: Quantitative data, should not be the center of attention of the question.

Comment: And, my question is not about position of black hole, my question is mentioned in its description.

Answer (score 2):

You have to consider the singularity and event horizon. By observing the orbits of nearby planets and such, we can calculate the approximate mass of the black hole, and thus where the singularity is. This then further gives us the Schwarzschild radius;

$R_{Schwarzschild}=\frac{2GM}{c^{2}}$

This defines the event horizon, thus allowing us to then calculate the distance to the 'black hole'. The black hole is the region of space within this event horizion.